# Acer swift 3 high CPU temperature and fan not running

Tags: drivers, 20.04, overheating, fan, temperature

I've upgraded to `Ubuntu 20.04 LTS`.

My computer is a `Swift-SF314-57` but I am experiencing issues with my CPU (`Intel® Core™ i5-1035G1`) temperature which is pretty high:

```
iwlwifi_1-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +57.0°C  

BAT0-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
in0:          12.98 V  

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +84.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +72.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:        +84.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:        +70.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:        +75.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

acpitz-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
temp1:        +27.8°C
```

I have done this commands `sudo sensors-detect --auto`:

```
Driver `coretemp':
  * Chip `Intel digital thermal sensor' (confidence: 9)

To load everything that is needed, add this to /etc/modules:
#----cut here----
# Chip drivers
coretemp
#----cut here----
```

I added them in the file as asked, then `sudo pwmconfig` however the detection seems to have an issue

```
/usr/sbin/pwmconfig: There are no pwm-capable sensor modules installed
```

Do you have any idea on how I could fix that?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Configuration

1. Computing device=Acer TravelMateB113
2. cpu = i3-2377 (Sandy Bridge), TDP=17watt[1]
3. sys = Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Situation:

1. permanently removed the rechargeable battery from computing device
2. upgraded dual install of Ubuntu 14+16 to Ubuntu 20
3. The system now randomly emergency shutsdown, sometimes even 5 secs after login to an account = 40 secs after boot (see [2])

Suspect: overheat

Diagnosis:

```
% grep -i -e therm /var/log/syslog*
```

No matches found except for `Registered thermal governor ...` and `thermald: [WARN] ...` Heat seemed to build up too fast up to emergency shutdown for any log facility to emit a warning or panic message.

Reading into the matter of system/intel-cpu heat reduction,
suggested topics:

- Running Average Power Limit – RAPL
- Power State (pstate)
- thermal daemon

The cpu does an emergency shutdown once 100C° have been sensored.

Question: Why does heat build up in less than half a second from 50°C to 100°C ?

Suspect: intel turbo boost
Disable it:

```
% cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/no_turbo

% echo "1" | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/no_turbo
```

On login to an account the fan still started to vent at limits ([2]).
And the system still did emergency shutdown once an internet-browser was executed.
Used

```
% top
```

to identify the most cpu% consuming processes on login to an account.

1. tracker-miner-fs
2. snap-store
   Both of these produce heavy io-load (disk read and also write, monitorable with i.e. iotop).
   Disabled trackers as suggested on Ubuntu help www-pages.

Turned attention to thermald, sensor-polling cpu heat at 1 Hz (once per sec), probably too slow to be useful in this scenario. As suggested in docs for thermald: disable thermald, reboot, launch it without daemon and read the log output to std_out on terminal:

```
% systemctl disable thermald
% reboot
% ps -e | grep thermald  # make sure that no thermald is running
```

thermald --no-daemon --loglevel=info  # or: --loglevel=debug

```
% # use 'systemctl enable thermald' to reenable
```

The man page of thermald suggests to write a custom 'thermal-conf.xml'. There is a man page with some examples: `man thermal-conf.xml`

Yet, disabling thermald was sufficient to have the fan start venting early (built for TDP=17watt it is but a tiny fan, and now starts venting at about 45°C) to countermeasure uprising processing pressure heat. A `ps auxc | grep -i therm` now results in `acpi_thermal_pm`.

Summary: disable { intel turbo boost, tracker-miner-fs, snap-store, thermald }

trouble solving time: 20h
Thanks to gnu/linux/gnome/debian/ubuntu + trouble solving volunteers

refs
[1] in plain terms: a rather weak design on cpu-heat; see Intel Inc defs for reference.

[2] askubuntu.com/questions/1260698/high-cpu-temp-on-boot-fan-noise-on-ubuntu-thinkpad-t490/1260716#1260716
"Ubuntu boots with the CPU frequency scaling governor set to performance..."